# Having trouble with query and subquery: SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

Here's what I'm trying to run but am getting an error. Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
   Client_Account_Name, 
   (
       select Distinct t1.Contact_email as temp3 
       from Order_Log_SFDC t1
       inner join
       (
          select max(Event_Date_Time) Event_Date_Time, Client_Account_Name
          from Order_Log_SFDC
          group by Client_Account_Name
       )  t2 on t1.Client_Account_Name = t2.Client_Account_Name
              and t1.Event_Date_Time = t2.Event_Date_Time
   ) as Email,

    MIN(Source) as source, 
    SUM(Final_Quote) as Total, 
    MIN(Event_Date_Time) AS min_date, 
    Max(Event_Date_Time) as max_date, 
    count(Distinct Event_Date_Time) as numOrders

FROM Order_Log_SFDC
Group By Client_Account_Name
```

This is the error:

> **SQL Error [512] [21000]:** Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   **SQL Error [512] [21000]:** Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   **SQL Error [512] [21000]:** Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>    **SQL Error [512] [21000]:** Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>             The cursor was not declared.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Given the error messages I am guessing your are using sql server? Have to be careful when tagging as mysql <> sql server. This error is because you have a subquery as a column. If that subquery returns more than 1 row the engine doesn't know what to do with it. Not really sure why you have three queries here all hitting the same table. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT
    Client_Account_Name,
    Email = CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(8), Event_Date_Time) + CONVERT(VARBINARY(200), Contact_email)), 9, 200)),
    source  = MIN(Source),
    Total = SUM(Final_Quote),
    min_date = MIN(Event_Date_Time),
    max_date = MAX(Event_Date_Time),
    numOrders = COUNT(DISTINCT Event_Date_Time)
FROM
    Order_Log_SFDC
GROUP BY
    Client_Account_Name;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I do have another question though. I'm trying to combine two tables with the same columns into a temp table and then get a result from the combined data but am getting an error saying "invalid object name ##t'

Comment: That just means that you're trying to reference a global temp table that hasn't been created or has already been dropped.

Comment: I just uploaded the code I'm using by updating my original post because it was too long to post as a comment. I am creating the temp table and only drop it til the end but for some reason the code runs for a bit before failing.

Comment: Please don't change the fundamentals of your question after you've been given an answer. Please create a new thread with your new question.

Comment: No worries. The key is that someone else is likely to have the same problem that you are. If the threat is "one problem and it's solution(s)", it stands to benefit the next person with the same issue. If it's allowed to morph into an endless chain of unrelated questions, no one knows what solution pertains to what question... Making it useless as a future reference.

Comment: Also... If you have questions about how/why that solution works, let me know. It's probably not immediately obvious to new developers.

Comment: Yes.. I'm not sure why declaring it as Total = SUM(Final_Quote) vs. SUM(Final_Quote) as Total works and what all the Convert/substring is doing? Thanks again

Comment: It's a solution that takes advantage two interesting properties of the BINARY data type. 1) When you convert a numerical or date data type to binary, SQL Server continues to sort it as it's original type (dates continue to sort as dates and number still sort numerically). 2) You can concatenate any binary value to any other binary value. So, what this is doing... convert the date to a BINARY(8) {datetime data type is 8 bytes} and convert the email to VARBINARY(200) {200 is just a number guaranteed to be longer than any legit email address}...

Comment: From there the two converted binary values are concatenated together (DATETIME + EMAIL)... By putting the DATETIME in the 1st position, the concat'd value can be sorted as a date and bring the email value along for the ride. So, taking the MAX(concat'd binary value) returns the most recent date AND the email address that was associated with it. From there, it's just a matter of retrieving the email address. This is done by splitting the binary value... We know that the DATETIME is taking up the first 8 bytes, so it's just a matter of grabbing 9-200 and converting it back to a VARCHAR(200).

Comment: The idea originated with this article... https://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/last-non-null-puzzle ........... The problem/question itself is different but the technique used to solve that puzzle is identical.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   Client_Account_Name, 
   (
       SELECT TOP 1 Contact_email 
       FROM Order_Log_SFDC t2
       WHERE t2.Client_Account_Name = t1.Client_Account_Name
       ORDER BY Event_Date_Time DESC
   ) As Email,
   MIN(Source) as source, 
   SUM(Final_Quote) as Total, 
   MIN(Event_Date_Time) AS min_date, 
   Max(Event_Date_Time) as max_date, 
   count(Distinct Event_Date_Time) as numOrders

FROM Order_Log_SFDC t1
Group By Client_Account_Name
```